# php open modify and save html file

Tags: php, html, dom, removeclass

in php I would like to open a html file, delete the content of the div(class Areas) and save it.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( "temp/page".$y.".xhtml" );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$pDivs = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='Areas']");
foreach ( $pDivs as $div ) {
  $div->parentNode->removeChild( $div );
}
echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTMLFile());
```

It doesn't work...

My html file look :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <div style="height:998px;">
    <img src="images/bg004.jpg" />
     <div class="class1">
         <div class="class2"></div>
         <div class="class2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Areas">
         <div class="Area"><a href="index.html"></a></div>
         <div class="Area"><a href="index.html"></a></div>
         <div class="Area"><a href="index.html"></a></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have this result :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <div style="height:998px;">
    <img src="images/bg004.jpg" />
     <div class="class1">
         <div class="class2"></div>
         <div class="class2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Areas">

    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank for your help

**UPDATE**

How to do the same thing but my file is now a xml ?

I test this :

```
    copy("temp/page".$y.".xhtml", "/temp/page".$y.".xml");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( "temp/page".$y.".xml" );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$pDivs = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='Area']");
foreach ( $pDivs as $div ) {
    $div->parentNode->removeChild( $div );
}
$dom->savexml();
```

And I have now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <div style="height:998px;">
    <img src="images/bg004.jpg" />
     <div class="class1">
         <div class="class2"></div>
         <div class="class2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Areas">
         <div class="Area"><a href="index.html"></a></div>
         <div class="Area"><a href="index.html"></a></div>
         <div class="Area"><a href="index.html"></a></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very nearly there. You just needed to change `Areas` to `Area` and then use `saveHtmlFile` instead of `saveHTML`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( "temp/page".$y.".xhtml" );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$pDivs = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='Area']");
foreach ( $pDivs as $div ) {
  $div->parentNode->removeChild( $div );
}
$dom->saveHTMLFile("temp/page".$y.".xhtml");
```

This is assuming you want to save the HTML back to the original document. Do note that DOMXPath will add a doctype to the top of your document, I assume that's okay?

Comment: I have a question, the new edited HTML file add me a doctype and a meta. I don't want! Do you know how delete this? I test to rename my xhtml file in xml but now the <div> isn't deleted...

Comment: Yes that will be because while DOMXPath seems willing to take your invalid XHTML and attempt to parse it, it will not generate invalid XHTML. If needs that doctype and meta to be fully valid.

Comment: I have upadted my question. Thx

Answer (score 4):

[`saveHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) just outputs the html as a string use [`saveHTMLFile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php) to save it as a file.

Comment: thx, I do it but nothing append. The html file is not modify.

Answer (score 3):

You want to remove the divs with class `Area`, so simply change the XPath query:

```
$pDivs = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='Area']"); // not 'Areas'
```

And of course you will also need to do something with the results, for example:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML()); // prints the result
```

Comment: Ok, thx I do this. So in echo htmlspecialchars($dom) It's OK. But my html file on the server isn't changed...